# php array formatting ( convert an array in to another array)

Tags: php, arrays, formatting

I have an array in php like the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 8
        )

     [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 27
        )

)
```

How can I convert it into the following format.

```
array(0,4,5,0,0,8,10,27);
```

Comment: could not get your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check

```
foreach($mainarray as $s){
    foreach ($s as $v){
        $str .=$v.','; 
    }
}
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine:

```
$array = array(array(1, 4), array(5, 0), array(0, 8), array(10, 27));

$result = array();

foreach ($array as $val)
{
  $result = array_merge($result, $val);
}

print_r($result);
```